# Wordpress on HTTPS and Apache Alias

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I am trying to setup our blog, but cannot crack the right configuration...

The folder structure is:

```
var/www/domain
| - website
| - webapp
| - blog
```

Apache Config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
ServerAdmin admin@example.com

# -------------------------------------
# ------        Web Stuff        ------
# -------------------------------------

# Website
DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/production/website/code/wwwroot
<Directory "/var/www/example.com/production/website/code/wwwroot">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

# Webapp
Alias /pages /var/www/example.com/production/webapp
<Directory "/var/www/example.com/production/webapp">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

# Blog
Alias /blog /var/www/example.com/production/blog
<Directory "/var/www/example.com/production/blog">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain_production_access.log combined
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain_production_error.log
LogLevel warn

# -------------------------------------
# -------------------------------------

# Catch any requests for example.com and redirect them to www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [NC,R=301,L]

# Catch any http requests (except for status check and those that originated from
# this server) and redirect them to https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https

RewriteRule !/api/aws/check https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]

# Django web service - all URLs beginning with /api
WSGIDaemonProcess www.example.com processes=8 threads=1 display-name=%{GROUP}

 ... FOLLOWED BY A LOT OF SETTINGS FOR API ...

 <LocationMatch "\.(jpg|css|gif|pdf|ico)$">
    SetHandler None
</LocationMatch>

# Zip output
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/html application/x-javascript application/javascript application/json
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
```

I have installed WordPress in blog directory and connected to database. But when I try to open https://www.example.com/blog I see the content but no styling (all assets coming from non-https address).

I couldn't access wp-admin, so I manually changed the urls in database to https, still cannot see any assets on blog page, and when trying to access wp-admin I get redirection loop.

Answer (score 0):

Installing [https plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https/) solved it. there were 2 separate problems:

1) infinite loop
2) assets being served from http

The plugin solved both, the first problem solved by adding .htaccess to the root (which I tried milion times, but apparently I must have made some mistake in the rewrite rules).

But that doesn't solve the issue with assets (I know, I tried/tested). That means this pugin has to do some magic in php as well, which by my logic is a pretty big issue in the wordpress itself...

Just as a reference, this is how the .htaccess looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```